# Реализация автоматического отката моего (и не только моего) минуса

Tags: предложение, вопросы

Как сообщество отнесётся к такой идеи?

Например, я вижу вопрос. И он мне откровенно не нравится по одному или нескольким параметрам, и, так и хочется поставить минус, например, за:

- **Прямое несоблюдение орфографических/пунктуационных правил** *этого языка*.
- **Домашние задания, которые должны решить участники**
- **Использование иного языка, в отличии от** *этого языка*.
- **Плохо оформленный вопрос**

Итак, ситуация номер 1:

Я вижу вопрос, вполне себе адекватный вопрос, но первый пункт явно указывает на то, что юзер просто не научился отличать -*ться* от -*тся* и всякое прочее, и он не носитель другого языка. Соотвественно, я ставлю минус этому вопросу с пометкой "Орфография/пунктуация", и как только кто-либо возложит на себя обязанность по редактированию всего этого, и правка будет утверждена, то я не против (и даже "за"!), чтобы мой минус автоматически откатился.

Ситуация номер 2:

Я вижу вопрос (а точнее, не вопрос, а домашку). Я ставлю минус этому вопросу, с пометкой "Домашнее задание без попыток решить его", и после этого, если участник поправит вопрос, приложит какие-то попытки решения, то минус должен автоматически откатиться.

Ситуация номер 3:

Бывает такое, что вопросы задают не *на этом языке*, и, в принципе, такой вопрос можно минусовать, и даже нужно. Я его минусую, с пометкой "Иной язык", какой-либо участник может отредактировать вопрос, сделать перевод, и тогда мой минус может автоматически откатиться.

Ситуация номер 4:

Плохо оформленный вопрос. Тут, я думаю, комментировать не надо. Это просто плохо оформленный, неброжно написанный, вопрос. Минус с пометкой "Плохо оформленный", и как следствие автоматический откат минуса, если его оформят как надо.

Во всех остальных случаях, вопросы либо не по теме, либо троллинг, и так далее... ставится обычный минус без какой-либо пометки, и это означает, что  такой минус автоматически откатываться вообще не будет.

---

Вопросы? Предложения?

Comment: проблема автоматизации в том, как решить, когда она должна применяться: если смотреть просто по части было редактирование или нет - то нет смысла добавлять, так как редактирование может быть совсем не связано с проблемой из-за которой был поставлен минус. Если же не просто факт редактирования, то как автоматически определить - была ли исправлена проблема из-за которой был минус или нет?

Comment: @Grundy, то есть никак не определить, даже если минус был поставлен с какой-то опреденной (из четырёх) меткой, да?

Comment: даже если добавить возможность указывать причину минуса - как определять, что причина устранена? Учитывая, что это должно происходить в автоматическом режиме.

Comment: @Grundy, ну, я думаю, правка может всё решить. Если участник (какой-либо) видит за что минусы, то принятая позже его правка по данному сабжу должна откатывать минус(а). Я вижу так.

Comment: То есть - при любой правке будет происходить автоматический откат? Тогда, будет слишком легко откатывать минус ничего не меняя в вопросе/ответе. И, в итоге, система не будет работать как задумывалось.

Comment: @Grundy, сейчас я дополню вопрос, постараюсь сделать некую графическую визуализацию.

Comment: @Grundy, откат будет происходить, только в том случае, если редактирование делалось именно с целью убрать минусы по по одному (или нескольким) пунктам.

Comment: И как определить с какой целью делалось редактирование? кто это будет определять? Достаточно ли одной цели или она еще и должна быть выполнена? например, при домашнем задании будет добавлен какой-то код, который может вообще не относиться к вопросу, цель очевидна - убрать минусы, результат - вопрос как был плохим так и остался плохим.

Comment: @Grundy, вот смотрите, примитивный пример: юзер тупо публикует вопрос с целью решить домашку, прикрепляет скрин, при этом, куча орфографических ошибок. Я ему ставлю "минус" по трём пунктам. 1) ``Домашка без попыток найти решение.`` 2) ``Орфография/пунктуация`` 3) ``Плохо оформленный вопрос``. Под минусом это всё отображается для широкой публики. Кто-то может внести правку по второму пункту. Минус откатится только по этому пункту, если правка будет утверждена. А вот автору вопроса следовало бы откатить минусы по первому пункту, и сделать хороший вопрос.

Comment: и опять возвращаемся к тому, что при любом редактировании будет снят _какой-то_ минус. Плюс непонятно как можно поставить минус по трем пунктам - это три минуса? и как он будет откатываться только по одному. Плюс не все правки требуют утверждения, то есть кто угодно может отредактировать - и минус должен откатиться. И все еще непонятно, как определять, что после правки проблема решилась?

Comment: Всем по минусу, и пусть никто не уйдёт обиженным! ^_^

Answer (score 6):

Если вы видите хороший, но плохо оформленный вопрос - стоит взять и подправить форматирование, а не минусовать. Минусы стоит ставить тем вопросам, которые **вы вообще не хотите видеть на сайте** - потому что именно к таким последствиям минусы и приводят.

Если вы считаете, что вопрос требует правки для получения полноценного ответа - стоит [проголосовать за закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Механизим закрытия делает именно то, что вы пытаетесь сделать минусами:

- Забрасывает вопрос в отдельную очередь, где другие участники могут проголосовать за закрытие.
- Пять голосов за закрытие помечают вопрос как "требующий правки".
- Правка автоматом помещает вопрос в очередь на открытие.

Голоса за закрытие (и за открытие) доступны от 3000 репутации.

---

Оформление и опечатки стоит просто исправлять.

Нет никакого смысла минусовать вопрос за  -ться/-тся. Представьте себя на месте задавшего вопрос, который вернется на сайт через сутки, и обнаружит свой ответ в глубоком -10 с припиской "иде**е** же!".

У нас технический сайт, стоит оценивать техническую сторону вопроса, а не правильность расстановки запятых.

Comment: Хорошо. Я вас понял. Всё, я могу удалить вопрос?

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto уже не сможете)

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto так дела не делаются здесь. Если бы каждый удалял вопрос после получения ответа, никакой базы вопрос-ответ не существовало бы.